# How to force using zxing lib with only my application?

Tags: android, zxing

Ok lets say there are 3 different applications which are using zxing lib on the phone. Whenever I want to open zxing with my own application android asks me whether to complete action using app 1 or app 2 or my own app. How do I force it to run only through my app without any dialog? Is there any chance to do it?

**EDIT**

In Additional to CommonsWare, you can do that if you want to handle barcode result on the 
other activity.

step 1: jump to method called handleDecode in Capture Activity. Add these lines after handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", rawResult.getText());
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

step 2: Do whatever want to do on the other activity's onActivityResult event.

PS: Thanks again to CommonsWare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there is no "zxing lib". You are supposed to use the Barcode Scanner application, tying it into your application at the activity level, ideally using their `IntentIntegrator` code. [Here is a sample application demonstrating this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing). The creators of ZXing specifically do not support or endorse baking the Barcode Scanner source code into another application.

However, given your symptoms, I have to assume that you are trying to add the Barcode Scanner source code to your own application.

You presumably have something like this in your manifest on the scanning activity's element:

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

You are not Barcode Scanner. Yet, this `<intent-filter>` claims that you are Barcode Scanner.

You need to remove this `<intent-filter>`, modify your copy of the Barcode Scanner source code to not require it, and then start up the scanning activity using the component-based `Intent` constructor (e.g., `new Intent(this, ThisIsYourRevisedScanningActivity.class)`).

Comment: last question: How do I send qrcode back to onActivityResult event of other activity? I mean, now I can scan it and handle the result there is no problem, but the thing what I need to send the result just after scanning process has finished to another activities onActivityResult.

Comment: @MustafaGüven: As I have not attempted to integrate Barcode Scanner's source into an application, I have no advice here -- sorry.

Comment: For the record you are welcome to reuse code from Barcode Scanner. It's the complete copying that's a problem, for many reasons, including the one here -- apps wrongly intercept Intents for BS.

Answer (score 4):

Just include this,this has done the needed for me..

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: this is more like a temporary workaround and it really works. However in this case your app will be treated by AOS as a BarCodeScanner app which is not true in most cases. And if you remove intent filters to avoid detecting your app as BarCodeScanner app this solution wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not allow you to set this on your own. Only a user can set the default application for an action. If on your phone, you want your app to handle that event, then check the Use as default box before selecting your app in the picker.

For security reasons, Android does not allow you to set your app as the default without user interaction as then a malicious app could tie itself as the default to various events.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to remove intent-filter like CommonsWare said, so it must be as follows:

```
<activity
       android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="landscape"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
</activity>
```

and instead of calling via external intent you should call zxing like:

```
private final static int ACTION_ZXING_SCANNER = 0x0000c0de; //IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE
private void startZxingScanner() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intents.Scan.ACTION);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_ZXING_SCANNER);
}
```

and then process result in `onActivityResult()` using request code `ACTION_ZXING_SCANNER`. The import string if needed:

```
import com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents;
```

note: this works for me and I added zxing project as a lib to my project so here it is - the "zxing lib" :)