# Intent zxing library on  Android

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force using zxing lib with only my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559577/how-to-force-using-zxing-lib-with-only-my-application)

I use zxing to scan QRCode in Android app. I use Intent to show it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.healthcode.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

It is working, but if I have more app installed that use Zxing lib, I have a list of app to open this intent.

How can I force my app to use my lib ? What is the best way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine you actually have two apps that respond to "com.google.zxing.client.android.healthcode.SCAN" since that is your own made-up string, so I assume that's a typo. (If it isn't you have more problems here, including using our namespace when you are not allowed to.)

The `Intent` that you are sending is wrong, it should be "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN'. Use `setPackage()` to specify the app that should handle it. To use Barcode Scanner, set "com.google.zxing.client.android".

Better still, use the supplied `IntentIntegrator` code in the project in `android-integration`.

Comment: Yes, you have reason, the Intent is com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN. I wrong to type. But how can i use setPackage() ?

Comment: Do i need to edit manifest ? That's my code but now i got ActivityNotFoundException:
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: That's right. It will make sure Barcode Scanner is used. That's the right way to do it though I'm still not clear on whether this is your desired effect. It should be...

Comment: Now i get this error: ActivityNotFoundException (without pkg it work but ask me what intent to use). I don't want show this list....

Comment: ... because you are not checking for the existence of Barcode Scanner. If you used IntentIntegrator like I suggested above it would be taken care of for you. Please read my reply completely first.

Comment: Ok, maybe i have not explain my problem. I don't want install Barcode Scanner, but i want include it on my app (lib folder). I need only in my app, without ask user to install it.

Comment: IntentIntegrator work and perhaps it is best to use the Barcode Scanner externally for update and other problem. Thanks Sean